# I purchased a few of these units and have no idea what they are. Is there anyone that might have some suggestions?

Tags: identification

[image]The item measures 1" wide and 1-1/4" high nad about 1/2" front to back

Comment: Why did you purchase these ? :D Anyway, please show a different angle. Looks like some connector breakout.

Comment: Can you add a pic with a ruler so the dimensions can be estimated? Particularly for the pins.

Comment: The pins sticking up very much suggest this is a connector for direct PCB mounting. A look 'into' the barrels might give an insight as what type of connector it is.

Comment: This is a device to separate punters from their money... :)

Comment: Looks high frequency.

Comment: I have to wonder, if you don't know what they are, why did you purchase them? Anyway, seconding @Oldfart: give us a view down the barrels of the connectors and it should help.

Comment: It's hard to tell - are those 4 little gold pins, inside 4 gold tubes, per side?  With nothing but air separating the pins from the tubes, or little mica discs?  If so, it is likely a very high frequency (and pricey) RF connector, something like 20GHz. If they are just machined solid pins, then considerably less high-frequency and exotic.

Comment: Look for "quadrax" connectors, maybe you can find the fit.

Comment: you could make a tie clip from those ... or a paper weight .......... they may be fiberoptic transceivers ......  is there a part number printed on the other side?

Comment: Twin dual pair connector adapters that we’re possibly cost-reduced out of a design now surplus/scrap.

Comment: Are you able to provide a picture looking in the front of the barrel?

Answer (score 2):

It looks similar to this Rosenberger HSD Fakra Plug. Maybe missing the plastic portion. You can look at the data sheet here and check measurements.Looks pretty close though.
https://rosenberger.de/ok/images/documents/db/D4S21J-40MA5-Y.pdf

[image]